# I have array in side array with different key I want fetch the particular array using particular key from HTML side in angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular6

```
sqlArray = [
  {
    module_idn: [
      {
        "K": "0",
        "V": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "K": "1",
        "V": "XYZ"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

this is my array I want to fetch the get the data by particular key

```
<select class="form-control select" name="{{fl?.table_field}}" [value]="fl?.default_value" [(ngModel)]="fl.default_value">
    <option *ngFor="let dynamic of sqlArray[fl.table_field]" value="{{dynamic.k}}">{{dynamic.v}}</option>
</select>
```

in HTML `fl.table_field` has the same key name i.e. "module_idn".

How do I fetch the particular array for display and in sqlArray key value can be multiple.

Comment: JS is case sensitive for keys in objects. it should be dynamic.K and dynamic.V

Comment: @Rajesh its give me the error cannot find the module_idn of undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Nested `ngFor`'s should do the trick. However you may want to consider flattening this data structure or extracting interesting part or finally extracting whole components to handle each thing (then you would have first `ngFor` to "slice" main array, and each nested array would be given to another component.

Comment: how? can you help me.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't understood your question :D You just need to select part of object for `option`s, so there is no need for nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a recursive search of the child structures. You could do a recursive search of n levels using a function like this

```
  findObjects(obj, targetProp) {
    let finalResults = [];

    function getObject(theObject) {
      let result = null;
      if (theObject instanceof Array) {
        for (let i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) {
          getObject(theObject[i]);
        }
      }
      else {
        for (let prop in theObject) {
          if (theObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            if (prop === targetProp) {
              finalResults.push(theObject);
            }
            if (theObject[prop] instanceof Object || theObject[prop] instanceof Array){
              getObject(theObject[prop]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    getObject(obj);
    return finalResults;
  }
```

To get the list of keys for 'K', you should call it like this and it will return an array.

```
this.findObjects(this.sqlArray, "K");
```

or in your ngFor like

```
*ngFor="let dynamic of findObjects(sqlArray, 'K')"
```